# Trying to join 2 tables to get a count of orders and grouped by email

Tags: join

I have two tables in DB Orders with columns Orders Id, Orders NO, Customer ID; Customer with columns Customer ID, Customer email.  I need a count of the orders for each customer and group by email with output something like

> customeremail@email.com 23

```
SELECT Customer.Customer Email,
Count Orders.Order ID,
From Orders,
Left Join Orders on Customer.Customer ID
Group by Customer.Customer email, Orders.Order ID
```

Comment: you should ttag your rdms also you should provice a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of close by using a `LEFT JOIN` but you should start with your `Customer` table like this:

```
SELECT Customer.[Customer Email], COUNT(Orders.[Order ID]) AS OrderCount,
FROM Customer,
LEFT JOIN Orders 
    ON Customer.[Customer ID] = Orders.[Customer ID]
GROUP BY Customer.[Customer Email]
```

Note this assumes the `Customer Email` field is **unique** in the `Customer` table, otherwise if two `Customers` can share the same email, then you should group on `Customer ID` instead. Also you should avoid spaces in your columns names, it's best practice to not use special characters.

---

Additional note, an edit suggestion was made to use `COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.[Order ID])` instead, on the query I suggested, in case `Order ID` was not unique in the `Orders` table. While it's a good thought, it's also an assumption (and likely not the case in this context). Using extra operators like `DISTINCT` (when not needed) could lead to alternative **execution plans** that are potentially less performant (e.g. `DISTINCT` will likely result in an additional sort operation to be performed). Again I think it's a good thought, but I don't like to make answers on assumptions when there are other potential consequences, so I think the query I proposed is sufficient unless OP provides any additional information that states otherwise.